# Unique constraint in laravel by multiple fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have this table :

[image]

In the code I put :

```
    $id = request()->route()->parameter('keyword')?->id;
    return [
        'key'  => ['required', 'unique:keywords,key,project_page_id,'.$id],
    ];
```

If I try to add a new item with key `addButton` and `project_page_id = 5`, I get 422 error with message : `The key has already been taken.`. I want to have unique `key` by project_page_id, how can i get to this ?

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel` has validation objects, where you get more powerful options. It has a unique validation object, and you can tweak the query, where i would think you want the following logic, to also check for the `project_page_id`.

```
'key'  => ['required', (new Unique('keywords', 'id'))->where('project_page_id', $id)],
```

Comment: I put like this : `['required', (new Unique('keywords', 'id'))->where('project_page_id', $id)]`. Is not working, now I can duplicate keys for same or different project_page_id

Comment: What is the value of dd($id); ?

Comment: is null for add and the id in case of edit

Comment: But i believe if you can create duplicate project page id's that id is null in those cases